# Kullback–Leibler divergence between multivariate t and the multivariate normal?

Tags: multivariate-normal-distribution, kullback-leibler, t-distribution, numerical-integration

I want to calculate the [Kullback–Leibler divergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kullback%E2%80%93Leibler_divergence) between a [multivariate $t$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_t-distribution) distribution and a [multivariate normal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution) distribution, for different values of the degrees of freedom $\nu$.

However, this requires a multiple integration that seems to be difficult to calculate numerically for dimensions larger than 2. Is there a known result to calculate this integral or a numerical trick?

I understand there are general multivariate numerical integration methods. I was just wondering if there is a simpler **ad hoc** tool I could use as these are popular distributions, so I guess there may be some simpler tools.

Comment: Monte Carlo integration?

Comment: @seanv507 Thanks, that is too general to be of any use, but I appreciate the pointer.

Comment: t-distribution is a scale mixture of Gaussian distributions and fining KL divergence to mixtures is notoriously difficult. You can lower bound on it if you are interested.

Comment: This paper has what you are looking for. The final solution is on page 8 and is quite cumbersome. https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/s40304-019-00200-8.pdf

Answer (score 2):

There is a numerical solution based on one-dimensional numerical integrals here:

[Kullback Leibler divergence between a multivariate t and a multivariate normal distributions](https://rpubs.com/FJRubio/DKLtn)

[image]

I doubt there is a closed form solution, but the 1D numerical integral seems simple.